# Loading D3 Module via HTML versus a Node Require Statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, electron

## Problem

Executing the following code produces different results depending on where the module was loaded.

```
d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log(data);
}
```

When the D3 library is loaded in the html file, with the following script tag

```
<script src="node_modules/d3/build/d3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

data from file `data.tsv`, in the above example, is imported into the variable `data` as expected.

When the library is imported from the node terminal (REPL) or a script, as shown below, the contents of `data` ends up being a three object array, where all objects contain `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80`.

```
let d3 = require('d3');

d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log(data);
}
```

## Disclaimer

This is an Electron application and the issue is occurring on a render process not the main process. D3 is being used to component the UI. The browser security [write up](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki#local-development) below, explains how to easily work around this by hosting files locally such as using a local web server or to use the Electron API to [access local files](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/file-object/).

## Question

**As stated, the D3 documentation team explains that [browser security limits file access](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki#local-development)**, but what is the functional difference(s) between these two imports and why does it work one way and not the other?

Comment: `d3.tsv` is just a wrapper on `XMLHttpRequest`. The request are always sent to the same domain of the original  request. In the case of `node.js`, the app is running local and the request is trying to access the local host for the `XMLHttpRequest` but the there is no http sever on the localhost. That is why you are getting `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80`

Comment: Interesting, though I'm still curious why it'd work if the only difference is how the D3 library is called, because there is no http server when the D3 library is referenced in the html file instead of a node `require()` statement.

Comment: Which node.js version are you  using? I am not able to repro the error you are getting. The difference is not is the d3 library but how node and your browser handle `XMLHttpRequest` to the local host.

Comment: I'm using node version `v7.9.0`. Also the browser is chromium as this is an Electron app.